# In python what is a response object returned from a website?

Tags: python, object, response, etsy

I'm trying to use the etsy API and I was finally able to get it running from the source.  I gave it my key, and it returned the following when printed out.

```
<etsy._v2.EtsyV2 object at 0xb7284ccc>
```

However I have no idea what to do with it. The [github-repo](https://github.com/fulfilio/etsy-python) doesn't have much documentation, and the command that is suppose to follow doesn't work. I read the [Etsy API](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/api_basics) and didn't find the mentioned command `getFrontFeaturedListings` like the github listed.

I've had this issue before with an HTTP response object and I was told to use response.content to check out more info on the object. It didn't work for this object so I'm wondering if there was a simple way to test any generic object, or at least see what this object contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt you can always use the dir built-in method on an arbitrary python object. This will show you methods and fields attached to the object. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Anyway, sorry to hear about the poor documentation of the library. Last time I used Etsy's API I just created a little class that used requests. It wasn't much work since Etsy lays out all of the URIs + documentation nicely on their developer site. https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/favoritelisting

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I was looking for thank you.